# Do multiplexers rely on values from all inputs before processing?

Tags: verilog, hardware, circuit, multiplexing

Assume I have a 2:1 multiplexer (MUX) with inputs A and B, selector S, and output C.

Assume A and B are both determined by some previous combinational logic.  The result from A has been found but B is delayed because it is still processing.  However, the multiplexer selector, S, selects A to be equal to the output C and therefore doesn't care what B is.  Does it matter that we do not yet know the value for B?  Or, do we need all values for the multiplexer to be known in order for the multiplexer to select the correct input?

Thanks!

Comment: is it a question about how the hardware works or about simulation?

Answer (score 1):

When `S` selects `A`, `B` is ignored.  Therefore, it doesn't matter that we do not yet know the value for `B`.

Similarly, when `S` selects `B`, `A` is ignored.